# Initialize const member and use parent constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initialization

Is there a way to initialize a const member in template when you inherit `T` and use `using T::T`? Here is an example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class A {
protected:
  int wake_up_time_;

public:
  A(int wake_up_time): wake_up_time_(wake_up_time) { }

  virtual void hello() const {
    std::cout << "I wake up at " << wake_up_time_;
  }
};

/* B classes inherit from A and have different members some of which vary in  
 * size and type                                                             */
class B1 : public A {
public:
  std::string b;

  B1(int a, std::string b): A(a), b(b) { }
};

class B2 : public A {
public:
  int c;
  double d;

  B2(int a, int c, double d): A(a), c(c), d(d) { }
};

template<class T>
class bird : public T {
  /* this function is more expensive in my case. */
  bool is_early_bird() const { // needs to be const as hello is const
    return this->wake_up_time_ < 6;
  }

  /* would like to have this instead */
  // const bool is_early_bird_;

public:
  /* which we assign in the constructor */
  using T::T;

  void hello() const override { 
    std::cout << (is_early_bird() ? "I am an early bird!" : "Getting up is hard...")
              << std::endl;
  }
};

template<class T>
class cat : public T {
  /* similar comments as in bird class */
  bool is_hunting() const {
    return this->wake_up_time_ < 5 || this->wake_up_time_ > 22;
  }

public:
  using T::T;

  void hello() const override {
    std::cout << (is_hunting() ? "Time to kill stuff" : "Time to sleep")
              << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<A> ptr;
  {
    ptr.reset(new bird<B1>(5, "..."));
    std::cout << "B1 has value " << dynamic_cast<B1*>(ptr.get())->b << std::endl;
  }
  ptr->hello();

  {
    ptr.reset(new cat<B1>(12, "xyz"));
    std::cout << "B1 has value " << dynamic_cast<B1*>(ptr.get())->b << std::endl;
  }
  ptr->hello();

  {
    ptr.reset(new cat<B2>(24, 3, 12.5));
    B2* l_ptr = dynamic_cast<B2*>(ptr.get());
    std::cout << "B2 has value " << l_ptr->c << " and " << l_ptr->d << std::endl;
  }
  ptr->hello();

  {
    ptr.reset(new B2(10, 7, 3.33));
    B2* l_ptr = dynamic_cast<B2*>(ptr.get());
    std::cout << "B2 has value " << l_ptr->c << " and " << l_ptr->d << std::endl;
  }
  ptr->hello();

  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
B1 has value ...
I am an early bird!
B1 has value xyz
Time to sleep
B2 has value 3 and 12.5
Time to kill stuff
B2 has value 7 and 3.33
I wake up at 10
```

What I want to get rid of is the (in this case simple) computation in `cat::is_hunting` and `bird::is_early_bird` and have const member instead. I also a lot function which takes a reference or a pointer to `B1` or `B2` classes as argument so it does not seem to be an option to have `public cat : public A` and `public bird : public A` class and end with 2x2 inherited B classes.

Comment: What is stopping you? What error do you get when you try? Isn't there a simpler code to reproduce?

Comment: @W.F. *Isn't there a simpler code to reproduce?* I wanted to stress that I have multiple classes like `B1` and `B2` and multiple classes like `cat` and `bird` to avoid comments that I could e.g., let `cat` inherit from `A`. Further, I also wanted to stress that `B1` and `B2` differ in the number of constructor arguments and their type.

Comment: @W.F. *What is stopping you? What error do you get when you try?* How do I initialize the class `bird` with `using T::T` and a `const bool is_early_bird_` member and no `bird::is_early_bird` function?

Comment: const non-static class members are to be initialized by constructor initialization list just like other non-static members...

Comment: I get that you didn't want to be accused to provide [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but still you should try to show [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes so how do you do that with `using T::T` and you want to use the member in a `const` function as in my example?

Comment: As I understand what you're asking - like [\[this\]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kvN84fGluyevwaGa)

Comment: No, I must not have made a clear example or you are not getting my question. It is more like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pexBBk18IOjqxUXZ).

Comment: aaam... [\[this\]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uCOmLcOrKPy4pVHy)?

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Will this work with c++11 only or does it use c++14 or later features?

Comment: My bet is it is c++11. Glad it helped.

Comment: You are correct. See [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) or the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W.F. gives an answer in the comment section. The answer is to change e.g., the `cat` class to

```
template<class T>
class cat : public T {
  const bool is_hunting_ = { this->wake_up_time_ < 5 || this->wake_up_time_ > 22 };

public:
  using T::T;

  void hello() const override {
    std::cout << (is_hunting_ ? "Time to kill stuff" : "Time to sleep")
              << std::endl;
  }
};
```

from

```
template<class T>
class cat : public T {
  /* similar comments as in bird class */
  bool is_hunting() const {
    return this->wake_up_time_ < 5 || this->wake_up_time_ > 22;
  }

public:
  using T::T;

  void hello() const override {
    std::cout << (is_hunting() ? "Time to kill stuff" : "Time to sleep")
              << std::endl;
  }
};
```

This is described [on this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

> **Member initialization**
>   Non-static data members may be initialized in one of two ways:
>   ...
>   2) Through a default member initializer, which is simply a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration, which is used if the member is omitted in the member initializer list.
>   ...
>
> **Usage**
>   The name of a non-static data member or a non-static member function can only appear in the following three situations:
>   1) As a part of class member access expression, in which the class either has this member or is derived from a class that has this member, including the implicit `this->` member access expressions that appear when a non-static member name is used in any of the contexts where this is allowed ...